# how to make a graph based on distance using one vector values

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:23, .Label = c("A", "AA", "AAA", 
"AAAA", "AAAAA", "AAAAAA", "AAAAAAA", "B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", 
"BBBBB", "BBBBBB", "BBBBBBB", "BBBBBBBB", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC", 
"CCCCC", "CCCCCC", "CCCCCCC", "CCCCCCCC"), class = "factor"), 
    relation = c(14.3, 17.7, 91.9, 272.5, 272.5, 33.2, 16.5, 
    16.7, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 33.2, 16.5, 33.2, 30.2, 30.2, 23.4, 
    23.4, 23.4, 23.4, 4.5, 23.4, 200.7)), .Names = c("ID", "relation"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

I am trying to make a network between each node.

I want to calculate the distance between every two rows and then plot it

I don't know if I am doing it right or not,

I do the following

```
mydistance<- as.matrix(dist(df$relation, method = "euclidean"))
library("igraph")

# Create a weighted complete graph from the distance matrix
g <- graph.adjacency(df$relation, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE)

# Chose the layout function
custom.layout <- function(g, ...) {
  layout.fruchterman.reingold(g, weights = E(g)$weight, ...)
}
```

I want to have something like this [enter link description here](http://forwardprogress.net/data-steps-effective-relationship-marketing-dean-delisle/)

Comment: What is it about the linked figure that you want to reproduce? Differences in node size, link opacity?

Comment: @jsta that link is just an example to show which types of visualization I am looking for. Does it make any sense ?

Comment: So you want a package recommendation? Try [ggraph](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggraph).

Comment: @jsta please look above igraph is the best I guess. If you can make a plot based on the distance that I calculated, I will accept your answer

Comment: *What* is your question? Are you doing it right? Is that the question?

Comment: @CPak my question is that how to do it? I tried with no sucess, so that it why I asked a question and I showed the effort I put on to make it